# GitHub - how to export repository specific issues into CSVExcel

Tags: github

How can I export GitHub-repository specific issues into CSV/Excel along with Labels, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369365/how-can-i-export-github-issues-to-excel, but the curl comment returns only 30 issues in JSON objects, even though there 125 issues in the repository

Comment: I am going with the approach in https://gist.github.com/marcelkornblum/21be3c13b2271d1d5a89bf08cbfa500e#file-export_repo_issues_to_csv-py using python code, but still the "projects" are not part of JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool: [GitHub CSV Tools](https://github.com/gavinr/github-csv-tools).